# Android: Bring back last activity with notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

Is there a way to bring back the latest activity when the user clicks on the notification? I don't want to start a new activity, just bring back the last/current activity. Is this even possible or is this maybe a bad idea?

My problem is my activity in the background starts an alarm sound (under specific conditions) and i want to bring back the user to this activity to stop the alarm.

Comment: The question is, how can i stop the alarm sound started by the previous activity when i start a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution by playing the alarm sound with the notification. :)